# Decimal not localized in MVC action called from AJAX post

Tags: .net, ajax, json, binding

I have an AJAX post from a German localized UI to a German localized Web API action. 
The object posted is a complex JSON which contains decimals. The values are inserted using the German locale (e.g. half of one is 0,5) and the JSON object parts are created from the element values.

The request is ARR routed from an MVC project to the Web API project.

The binding in the action is done by the framework, there is no interfering in the process. 
The bounded decimal fields of the object are 0 when the values contain comma and proper decimal values when values contain dot (which does not happen in the normal flow).

My assumption is that the JSON to .NET binding should care about the locale but apparently this is not happening. 
The questions are: is my assumption correct or not?
If it is, what are the possible reasons for the wrong binding?

Thank you, mosu.

I fixed the problem by formatting on the client side. 
But I am still very interested in the questions's answer!

Comment: can you post your json result, and how you produce the result|? In worst case you can add decoration on the entity to format it as you need.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the JSON result. JSON is being posted and it looks as normal as myObj {"field": "value"}. The problem can be simply solved replaceing the comma with a dot in the "value" but I'm interested if my assumption is correct or not.

Comment: how about you add the format the result to string (number).ToString(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture) to CurrentCulture (depends which you have set)

Comment: There is no place to add that as I am using the default ASP.NET MVC binding. The means the action is public void ActionName(MyComplexObject param) and then param is created by the default model binder.

Comment: how about put decoration on your entity for formatting?

Comment: How would you toggle that based on the current locale?